# ASM: Decrement content of specific address

Tags: assembly, stack, decrement, indexed

I need to decrement some bytes on/from the stack at a given address (indexed from esi).

```
pop esi ;
```

Now changing would not be a problem, I simply can do

```
mov [esi+13], al ;
```

to store the content from al in esi+13.

But how can I decrement what is in "esi+13".

E.g. value of esi+13 = 0xFF → New value of esi+13 = 0xFE.

I tried different things like

```
dec [esi+13] ;
sub [esi+13], 1; 
dec esi+13;
```

and so on, but I didn't find a solution.

I don't know which bytes will be in "esi+13" so I can't move the "result"
to the address, I really have to decrement it.

Comment: What do you mean you can't move a result to a location for which you have a pointer in esi?   I can understand why you don't *want* to do it in baby steps, but it should be *possible*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
dec byte ptr [esi+13]
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea.
Using nasm it’s simply "dec byte [esi+13]" :)